# detecting different screen touches after searchview click in order to remove keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, searchview

Here is my current layout -

[image]

The issues I am facing with my searchview are the follows -

1) when clicking the searchview one, the text cursor indicator will never go away, even after I am pressing the back button. How can I make it dissapear when removing the focus?

2) The main issue I am facing right now is not being able to remove it's focus without back-pressing.  I have seen many other threads about how to hide the keyboard - that's great, but where do I trigger these lines of code? What I want to achieve is when pressing on anything other than the SearchView or the keyboard - dissmiss the keyboard and remove the textview focus.

Here is my XML file, for any reason needed in order to assist me -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:paddingStart="14dp"
        android:paddingLeft="14dp"
        android:paddingEnd="14dp"
        android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_marketplace_title"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_searchview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        android:queryHint="Search..."
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_discover_products_from_myverte"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_vendors_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_marketplace_vendor_row_item" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/very_light_grey"
                android:paddingStart="14dp"
                android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="14dp"
                android:text="@string/fragment_marketplace_featured_products"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_marketplace_products_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/very_light_grey"
                tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_marketplace_products_row_item" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The hard way is to attach click listener manually on each view in this specific layout and hide keyboard when it's no necessary.

Or to create some global keyboard handler that initialize click listeners automatically for this `ViewGroup`, if the `View` is not `instance of` `EditText`(`SearchView` is `instance of` `EditText`) so hide keyboard, something like this:

```
public void initClickListeners(View view) {
    if (view != null) {
        if (!(view instanceof EditText)) {
            view.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
                tryToHideKeyboard();
                return false;
            });
        }
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            view.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    tryToShowKeyboard();
                }
            });
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
                initClickListeners(innerView);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initClickListeners(view)//root layout or fragment's View
}
```

Comment: Oh deer, this seems really messy. Isn't there any simpler way ?